# Display Output Panel from Console Component to Window.Top

Tags: visualforce, javascript, console, custom-console-components, popup-window

I am trying to display an [output panel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputPanel.htm) on the top window from a console component in Salesforce Classic.

Is this possible?

I've looked into [Window.Top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top), but I am failing to understand how I incorporate this into displaying a Visualforce component on the top frame.

If this is possible, any information on implementing this would be appreciated.

Update:

I've looked into javascript and jquery for appending a div or another element to the top window (the main console page) from the component, but I receive Cross Site Policy errors, but, I am not using any external sites and the urls in the error are the same URL. Ex: https://c.cs99.visual.force.com/apex/VisualForce_Test_Page?isdtp=vw&sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fcs99.salesforce.com&nonce=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Update 2:

Is there anything I can do to make this question more clear / is the title representative of the question?

Comment: Is it classic or lightning?

Comment: This would be for Salesforce Classic.